# Collectionview Issue in ipod

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have Collectionview in my project...its correctly working in ipad and iphone..but not in ipod...version of the ipod id IOS7..Can anyone tell me what is the issue..what i have to do...
My code is following

```
     _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 0,       self.view.bounds.size.width, height) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]    forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_collectionView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [_collectionView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];


     - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
    return arrayMonths.count;
     }

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to - dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
      - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
       for(UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
       }
       MonthView *month=[arrayMonths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       if ([month.strMonthName isEqualToString:@"February"]) {
        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -5, cell.frame.size.width, 40)];
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"KiCalName"],month.strYear]];
        label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:12.0]];
        [cell addSubview:label];
        [month setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, month.frame.size.width, month.frame.size.height)];
        }else if([month.strMonthName isEqualToString:@"January"] || [month.strMonthName  isEqualToString:@"March"]){
        [month setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, month.frame.size.width, month.frame.size.height)];
        }
       [cell addSubview:month];
       [hud hide:YES];
       return cell;
        }

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MonthView *monthOld=[arrayMonths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGRect rectNew=CGRectMake(monthOld.frame.origin.x, monthOld.frame.origin.y, monthOld.frame.size.width+40, monthOld.frame.size.height+40);
    MonthView *month=[[MonthView alloc]initWithFrame:monthOld.frame andYear:monthOld.strYear andMonth:monthOld.strMonthName andNoOfDays:monthOld.noOfDays andArrayOffDays:monthOld.arrayOFF andArrayOnDays:monthOld.arrayONN];
    [month setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rectNew];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [month setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, month.frame.size.width, month.frame.size.height)];
    [view addSubview:month];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setShowCloseButton:NO];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:view andAnimated:NO];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MonthView *month=[arrayMonths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"month name %@",month.strMonthName);
   NSLog(@"month %@",month);
   CGSize height;
   height=CGSizeMake(105, 155);
    if ([month.strMonthName isEqualToString:@"January"]) {
        height=CGSizeMake(105, 190);
        NSLog(@"called");
    }else if ([month.strMonthName isEqualToString:@"February"]){
        height=CGSizeMake(105, 190);
        NSLog(@"called");
    }else if ([month.strMonthName isEqualToString:@"March"]){
        height=CGSizeMake(105, 190);
        NSLog(@"called");
    }else{

    }
    return height;
}


-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue ? what problems do u face when running on iPod ?

Comment: [cell.contentView addSubview:]; instead of cell addSubview

Comment: @JanakNirmal  its getting crash..

Comment: What is the issue? Please clarify where the crash happens?

Comment: Can you post a crash log, so that we can help ? Or what you can do is put a break point from Breakpoint Navigator->Click Plus(Bottom Left)->Add All exception, and now the main part just put break point at appDidFinishLaunching. Now when app crashes you would be able to see where exactly it stops executing in issue navigator.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that You are dequeing the cell,

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**The thing is that you are not checking for nil..!!!**

Use the following condition,

```
if(cell==nil)
{
//then alloc cell
}
```